# Shreded system_health ExEvent not returning all node information

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, xml

SQL Server is not returning all node information when I shred the deadlock XML from the 2012 system_health Extended event.

When I run the following query

```
SELECT  CAST(event_data.value('(event/data/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS XML) AS DeadlockGraph 
FROM    ( 
        SELECT  XEvent.query('.') AS event_data 
        FROM    (    -- Cast the target_data to XML  
                    SELECT    CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TargetData 
                    FROM      sys.dm_xe_session_targets st 
                    INNER JOIN
                            sys.dm_xe_sessions s 
                            ON s.address = st.event_session_address 
                    WHERE   name = 'system_health' 
                    AND     target_name = 'ring_buffer' 
                ) AS Data -- Split out the Event Nodes  
        CROSS APPLY 
                TargetData.nodes('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData ( XEvent ) 
        ) AS tab ( event_data )
```

at our Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 instance all node information is returned along with descriptions i.e.

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process10e26bc8" />
  </victim-list>
<process-list>
<inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 26 Object Id = 1641213047]   
</inputbuf>
</process-list>
  ...
...
...
</deadlock>
```

However when I run it against our Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5548.0 instance all node information and descriptions are stripped out and only the text is returned i.e

```
Proc [Database Id = 26 Object Id = 1641213047]
```

What might cause this? The full XML hierarchy is outputted at our 2012 instance if I remove the `SELECT  CAST(event_data.value('(event/data/value)[1]','varchar(max)')` part from the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is a bit off from what I end up using, however I actually parse out a bit of information and do not just return the XML.

The specific parts of your query that don't look right is with outside FROM you have `AS tab ( event_data )` and then you are referencing that as `event_data.value` in your top `SELECT`.

I would change that around to just have `AS tab` and then reference your `CROSS APPLY` in your `SELECT`. So it would just something like this:

```
SELECT XEvent.query('(event/data/value/deadlock)[1]') AS DeadlockGraph 
FROM ( 
    SELECT XEvent.query('.') AS XEvent 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT CAST(target_data AS XML) AS TargetData 
        FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets st 
        JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions s ON s.address = st.event_session_address 
        WHERE s.name = 'system_health' AND st.target_name = 'ring_buffer' ) AS Data 
    CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('RingBufferTarget/event[@name="xml_deadlock_report"]') AS XEventData ( XEvent ) 
    ) AS tab;
```

Comment: that works perfectly, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/accidental-dba [Troubleshooting SQL Server: A Guide for the Accidental DBA] this looks to be by design.

> **Changes to Extended Events in SQL Server Denali**
>
> At the time of the
> final edits of this chapter, SQL Server Denali CTP3 was released, with
> changes associated to how the Extended Events targets store XML data
> inside of the value element of the Event XML  output. Listing 7.5
> shows the use of the .value() method from XML in SQL Server, but in
> Denali CTP3, a .query() method has to be used to retrieve the
> deadlock graph from the Event XML output.

Additional information : [Extended Events Changes in SQL Server 2012 – Event XML for XML data elements](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/extended-events-changes-in-sql-server-2012/)

Comment: How does this indicate it is by design?

Comment: passage specifies that 2012 requires a .query() method to shred the XML whereas 2008R2 can be read with a .value() method.